# Execute function only once in a infinite loop on blender game engine?

Tags: python, game-engine

I'm new to blender and python..I want to clear the input serial buffer of the blender game engine before reads data from it.

I have used `GameLogic.SerialPort.flushInput()` to clear the buffer. I have connected "always" sensor with the "True" level triggering.Therefor code can run infinitely.

I only need to clear the input buffer once in the loop but it always clear the serial buffer..

Any ideas how to clear serial buffer once in the infinite loop...

```
Blender code

import GameLogic
import serial


port = 'COM12' 

try: 
    GameLogic.SerialPort 
except: 
    GameLogic.SerialPort = serial.Serial(port,115200) 


GameLogic.SerialPort.flushInput()
.
.
.
rest of the programm
```

Comment: Use a control variable, and check it before trying to flush; Or do that outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for replying me..I have tried that.but here I didn't use any loop in the blender python programme .Loop was created by "true level triggering sensor" in the logic editor .Therefor it again flush the input buffer.